# Permission Justification in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm new in Devloper so not familiar about few things.

Can anyone help me adding Permission Justification?

PERMISSION JUSTIFICATION
A permission is either one of a list of known strings, such as "activeTab", or a match pattern giving access to one or more hosts.

tabs   _________________________________________ ?

activeTab  _________________________________________ ?

Host Permission  _________________________________________ ?
A host permission is any match pattern specified in the "permissions" and "content_scripts" fields of the extension manifest.

I'm not sure what exactly to fill on this. Still learing. If anyone can help me with this?
I'd really appreciate it.

I'm using below manifest.json

"permissions": [ "storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "2",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "options.html", "Privacy-Policy.html" ]
}

Comment: Where's the option of adding all these info? I also got error but do not know where to put it

Answer (score 1):

you need to clarify why do you need these permissions.

It's a bit mess of how you handling this permissions.

you request `tabs`: it can access any tab that user open/updated. get the url, content. etc. it's a very sensitive permission. why do you need it?

then you request `activeTab`, it only works when user clicks the extension icon or context menu item, to get current active tab permissions. it's a low sensitive permission. still, why do you need it?

`storage`: to store data in chrome extension's storage. normal permission, not sensitive.

then you come with 3 host permission, why do you need permissions to all urls? seems you don't understand Chrome extension permissions, yet why you copy code from other place and upload to chrome web store? Chrome web store review is pretty strict now, you need to understand your extension first, try to request as less permissions as you can.

Comment: What is the difference between the host permission, tabs, and content-scripts URL matching?

Comment: @rbansal `host permission` gives you the ability to send CORS requests to these hosts, `tabs` let you get all information in the tabs(checkmy original answer), `content-scripts` URL matching lets you inject your scripts/css to matched url.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to understand extension permissions, before publishing to the Web Store. Excessive permissions with vague explanation is a big red flag for Web Store reviewers and should be for any user installing the extension.

Still, I want to shed some light on the original question. Google does not expect that you will write a super technical and verbose explanation. It just has to make sense in the context of your extension. I have passed Web Store review process with quite short, but on point explanations.

I wrote an opinion piece on [required permissions and providing justifications](https://www.extension.ninja/blog/post/public-chrome-extension-permission-justification) after losing half of my active users after extension update once.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Script justification
It is used to execute the content script and other CSS files for the extension message showing on page.

2.)  Storage justification
It is used as the storage container to store the data of login user and comments of users.

3.) Tabs justification
It is used for accessing multiple tabs for login and adding permissions from external host.

4.) Host Permission justification
We declare the URLS of webpages where our content script will work in host permissions, therefore we allow all http and https links.